# Delete from list for a certain value

Tags: c#, list, class

I have mini class, which I save in List. Now I must delete in list, lines where **numRect = -1**.  How can I do it?

```
double pointX, pointY;
int numRect;
public PointsSelectedSources(double x, double y, int numRect)
{
    pointX = x;
    pointY = y;
    this.numRect = numRect;
}
public int NumRect
{
   get
    {
       return numRect;
    }
   set
    {
       numRect = value;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'd avoid naming the class value and the constructor property both numRect, even if the code understands which you mean, it's bad form and makes it harder for others to read your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `miniClassList` be the List then you can do something like the following to remove all objects from that list which are having numRect = -1;

```
miniClassList.RemoveAll(x=> x.numRect == -1);
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iWzsYY) for more clarification